# Function that accepts functions and returns an expression containing their partial derivatives

Tags: function-construction, calculus-and-analysis

I would like create a function that takes functions as input and includes different partial derivatives of the input functions, for simplicity's sake say:

$\qquad m(f(x,y),g(x,y))=f_{xxx}(x,y)+g_{xyy}(x,y)$

I've tried looking but couldn't find a solution to this type of problem here, how would I create the function $m$?

*Clarifcation on input functions: I want it to work for any function I've defined myself, like  `func[x_, y_] := 1 + x y + Sin[x + y]` (guess that's the syntax still new to mathematica).*

Comment: Does this work? `m[f_, g_] := 
 Fold[D[#1, #2] &, f[x, y], {x, x, x}] + 
  Fold[D[#1, #2] &, g[x, y], {x, y, y}]`, or perhaps this `m[f_, g_] := Derivative[1, 2][g][x, y] + Derivative[3, 0][f][x, y]` ?

Comment: When you write " take functions" do you mean function symbols such as `Sin` or 'f`, expressions such as `1 + x y + Sin[x + y]`, or pure functions such as `(1 + #1 #2 +Sin[#1 #2])&`?

Comment: @m_goldberg I'm not sure on the difference but I want to be able to give it any arbitrary function I can define myself, I guess that would be expressions like `1 + x y + Sin[x + y]`

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the comments after the clarification of OP. Depending on what exactly one wants as input and output of the desired function `m` the approach differs slightly:

```
m1[f_,g_,{x_,y_}]:=Derivative[1,2][g][x,y]+Derivative[3,0][f][x,y]
m2[f_,g_]:=Derivative[1,2][g][x,y]+Derivative[3,0][f][x,y]
m3[f_,g_]:=Derivative[1,2][g]+Derivative[3,0][f]
```

`m1` returns the sum of derivatives evaluated at the variables `x` and `y`, `m2` returns the sum of derivatives evaluated at the global symbols `x` and `y` (might be set to a value) and `m3` returns a pure function for the sum of derivatives:

```
y=a;
f[x_,y_]:=1+x y+Sin[x+y]
g=1+#1 #2+Sin[#1 #2]&;

m1[f,g,{x1,y1}]
m2[f,g]
m3[f,g]
```

returns

> [image: result]

where `f` is a function with named arguments set using `SetDelay`, `g` is a pure function with unnamed arguments, and `y` is a global variable set to the (here undefined) symbol `a`. The definitions for `m1`, `m2` and `m3` work only with functions, not with expressions. For expressions one would need something along the lines

```
ClearAll[x, y]
m4[f_, g_, {x, y}] := D[f, {x, 3}] + D[D[g, x], {y, 2}]
m4[1 + x y + Sin[x + y], 1 + x y + Sin[x + y], {x, y}]
```

returning `-2 Cos[x + y]` as expected. In all cases one has to be car full with the function arguments/global symbols: e.g. `m4` will not work if `x` or `y` are set to non-symbol objects (like e.g. `y=42`).